# Sys schema on Cloud SQL MySQL 2nd gen

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I enabled performance schema flag on my Cloud SQL MySQL 2nd gen so the `performance_schema` becomes available but I'm still missing the `sys` schema.

I think that during my experiments I saw it few times on some instances but I'm not able to find specific steps to turn it on on current production.

Can anybody help?

Comment: I had to reboot my instance before the sys schema database was visible. I had created the instance, imported my other databases and the sys schema database was not present. After hours of trying to figure this out I noticed something in the documentation that made me think of restarting the instance, once I did the sys schema database appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Sys schema is enabled by default from 5.7.7 and higher. If you have a 5.7 instance, it will not include the sys schema from the new version. In any case, if is not there there would not be any problem by manually installing  and enabling it.

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-schema.html) indicates that it's requirement depends on how the database is initialized.

Comment: The instances are 5.7.14 (from the beginning), so that's why I expected it to be there by default. Unfortunately I can't install it manually, as it's cloud service (so no direct access to server) and SUPER privilege is disabled.

Comment: This looks like something missing from the initial create/bootstrap. This could be fixed by an OS-level reboot or recreate. Neither of these is really accessible by you. Could you open an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=1010440) so one of the reps can have a look. Please be aware though this is trivial to do this will incur downtime.